# How to regex multiple times powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am just learning powershell and cant find how to run differents regex with powershell.

```
$input_path = 'C:\site-download\input.txt'
$output_file = 'C:\site-download\output.txt'
$regex = '(?<month>VPIP<\/span><span class=""right"">\d{2}.\d{1})'
$regex2 = '(?<month>VPIP<\/span><span class=""right"">\d{2}.\d{1})'
$regex3 = '(?<month>VPIP<\/span><span class=""right"">\d{2}.\d{1})'
$regex... = '(?<month>VPIP<\/span><span class=""right"">\d{2}.\d{1})'

select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches} | % { $_.Value }| 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '</span><span class=""right"">', ' = '} > $output_file
```

`$regex`
 works good, but how can i add `$regex2` and `$regex3` ... to outputfile?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just need a small change to your last section of your pipeline. Instead of using `> $output_file` just pipe the output of the `foreach` loop to `Out-File` cmdlet. So you should be able to have your last line of code look like this:

```
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | 
    % { $_.Matches} | % { $_.Value } |
    Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '</span><span class=""right"">', ' = '} | 
    Out-File $output_file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that did the work.

I also replace Out-File with Add-Content.

Comment: @Elx That works but understand that `Add-Content` has to convert the output to string before it writes it to the file, where `Out-File` will just output it to the file. You might see format change in your file depending on what you pipe to each.